# How to manipulate image (crop and resizing) after take photo or select photo from library using ionic 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

basically, I need to manipulate the picture that I select before viewing it in it's place in HTML page.
what I did so far is action sheet that have two options Load image or pick image :

```
async selectImage() {
const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
header: 'Select Image source',
buttons: [{
  text: 'Load from Library',
  handler: () => {
    this.pickImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
  }
},
{
  text: 'Use Camera',
  handler: () => {
    this.pickImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
  }
},
{
  text: 'Cancel',
  role: 'cancel'
}
]
});
}
```

and this is pickImage function

```
pickImage(sourceType) {
const options: CameraOptions = {
quality: 100,
sourceType,
destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
correctOrientation: true,
};
this.camera.getPicture(options)
.then((imageData) => {
this.crop.crop(imageData, {quality: 100 });
this.serviceps.logo = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
}, error => console.error('Error cropping image', error));

}
```

so now how can I add the cropping and editing image just right after choosing it ? I've been trying since yesterday but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Use this Plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/crop

Comment: yes sure I used it but it didn't work for me. Thank you

Comment: its because your are getting `base64` and this plugin support `FILE_URI`. 
Change your camera code from `this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` to `this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`.

Comment: Reduce the image quality also. 

quality: 100 => quality: 50

It will reduce your image size

Comment: @HassanAli it's not working :'((((((

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib do I have to change another thing in the code? because after your modification, when I pick a pic it displayed nothing just white bg.

Comment: Yes your have to parse it to show. previously you were using base64 and base64 is compatible with `img` tag. now its a file URI. google it how to show file URI in img tag in ionic.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I should use readAsDataURL(path, file) ? method ?

Comment: any solution for this issue?